# Javascript body dont scroll parent while child hovered

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eXAmq/)

```
<style>
#scrollable{
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    overflow: scroll;
}

#contents{
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    position: relative;
}

#element{
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    width: 200px;
    height: 80px;
}

</style>
<div id="scrollable">
    <div id="contents">
        <div id="element">
            While this is hovered, #scrollable should not scroll
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I prevent some scrollable element from scrolling, without removing the scrollbars, while hovering another element, that is not scrollable in similar fashion when there is a scrollable within a scrollable.

Comment: You can't prevent the scroll event, so you'll have to remove the scrollbars or use an element as overlay etc.

Comment: I don't know what you are asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#element').on({
'mousewheel': function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    },
'DOMMouseScroll': function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
}
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eXAmq/4/)

Comment: Just what I was looking for, this hoever will not work for firefox, youll need other event indentifier

Answer (score 0):

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eXAmq/1/)

Because you cant interrupt and cancel the scroll event directly, using jQuery, you can simply alter the overflow property of scrollable elements:

```
$('#element').on('mouseover',function(){
    $('#scrollable, html, body').css('overflow','hidden');
});
$('#element').on('mouseout',function(){
    $('#scrollable, html, body').css('overflow','auto');
});
```

Comment: All is great, but i need those scrollbars